# don't get currency symbol from NumberFormatter

Tags: swift, nsnumberformatter

The output of following Code is: **ARS 59.00**. Why is there no symbol printed?

```
let formatter = NumberFormatter()
formatter.currencyCode = "ARS"
formatter.numberStyle = .currency
print(formatter.string(from: NSNumber(value: 59.00)) ?? "na")
```

Comment: The key take-away from the below answers is that the international currency symbol for Argentine Pesos is `ARS`, so any time your Locale does not select Argentina as its culture, that's going to be the symbol. When your locale selects Argentina as its culture, then the currency symbol will be `$`, plus there will be a space between the `$` and the number (as opposed to selecting the US culture, where there is no space). Whether the `$` is printed before or after the number generally depends on the language, rather than culture selection. What output do you expect here, and over what Locales?

Comment: I think I was a bit confused because I expected $ as the symbol. But this clarifies it thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Forcing a Custom Locale

To display currency, you will need to show the currency symbol ($, €, ¥, £) for the current locale.

*NumberFormatter will show the correct symbol, and the formatting that you might not realize is very different from what you're used to. Different countries use different decimal separators and grouping separators—take a look!*

In the USA: $3,490,000.89

In France: 3 490 000,89 €

In Germany: 3.490.000,89 €

See: [How to Use NumberFormatter (NSNumberFormatter) in Swift to Make Currency Numbers Easy to Read](https://supereasyapps.com/blog/2016/2/8/how-to-use-nsnumberformatter-in-swift-to-make-currency-numbers-easy-to-read)

So in your case it would be:

```
let formatter = NumberFormatter()
formatter.currencyCode = "ARS"
formatter.numberStyle = .currency
formatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "es_AR")
print(formatter.string(from: NSNumber(value: 59.00)) ?? "na")
```

Comment: There is no need to convert `Double` to `NSNumber`. You can use `Formatter`'s `string(for: Any)` method.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
let formatter = NumberFormatter()
formatter.numberStyle = .currency
formatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "es_AR")
print(formatter.string(from: NSNumber(value: 59.00)) ?? "na")
```

check the local identifier here: https://gist.github.com/jacobbubu/1836273

Comment: The [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72755732/dont-get-currency-symbol-from-numberformatter#comment128514386_72756108) above applies here as well